# Codeigniter list only files non-recursively

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to list the names of files from a specific location, without names of the subdirectories and files they may contain.

I've used CI's directory_map function with a success, but had to make a small workaround to get rid of the folder names in not quite a neat way:

```
$files = directory_map('src/img/example/', 1);

foreach($files as $i => $file) {
    if(strpos($file, '\\') !== false) {
        unset($files[$i]);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there has to be a way easier and better solution, but had no luck finding it

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: both get_filenames and get_dir_file_info functions return the name of the subdirectory in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of filenames in a one-liner, using `scandir()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Here's an example that does an array_diff() to remove the "." and ".." directories.

```
 $files = array_diff(scandir('src/img/example'), array('..', '.'));
```

You can also use `array_filter()`.

```
$files = array_filter(scandir('src/img/example'), function($item) {
  return !is_dir('directory/' . $item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible option would be to use a `DirectoryIterator`

```
$arrFiles = [];

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('src/img/example/') as $objFile) 
{
    if($objFile->isFile()) $arrFiles[] = $objFile->getFilename();
}
```